# Quickbooks InventoryItemAdd COGSAccountRef Not accepting it's requested datatype

Tags: xml, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to create an item programatically in Quickbooks Desktop Version 15.0. I am using the Quickbooks SDK 13.0.

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"> 
<ItemInventoryAddRq> 
<ItemInventoryAdd> <!-- required --> 
<Name >Cash Sales</Name> <!-- required -->
<IncomeAccountRef> <!-- optional --> 
<FullName >Food Sales</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</IncomeAccountRef>
<AssetAccountRef> <!-- optional --> 
<FullName >Food Sales</FullName> <!-- optional -->
<COGSAccountRef>
<FullName>Cost of Goods Sold</FullName>
</COGSAccountRef>
</AssetAccountRef>
</ItemInventoryAdd>
</ItemInventoryAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

I am receiving this error from the xml validator:

```
Src Text: <COGSAccountRef>
Reason: Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.
```

COGSAccountRef is requesting a STRTYPE variable, which it is being given, but it doesn't want to accept it. If I remove this tag, the validator will say it is a valid xml code, but I get a response from quickbooks saying:

```
<ItemInventoryAddRs statusMessage="There was an error when saving a Item Inventory list, element "Cash Sales". QuickBooks error message: A COGS account must be specified." statusSeverity="Error" statusCode="3180"/>
```

I've tried also using a ListID instead, as well as creating the item manually in quickbooks, then querying quickbooks for the xml that is stored for that item to use it's COGSAccountRef xml.

I also have inventory enabled in quickbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had my tags out of order, in case anyone needs to know in the future. I just moved COGSAccountRef up above AssetAccount and it worked.